# No GUI windows on Linux. Probably a problem with wxPython package

Tags: linux, user-interface, simulation, intel, simics

I'm trying to use Simics on Linux but I can't get the serial and graphical console windows to popup. The simics shell itself and the whole simulation seems to work. The only clue of what's going wrong I found by trying to use the win-about command. That gives me the following error:

`simics> win-about

Failed to load the wxPython module needed for the GUI to load.

Error message: "Failed importing the 'wx' module: partially initialized module 'wx' has no attribute 'version' (most likely due to a circular import)"`

I have wxPython package installed but it's probably not used anyway since simics comes with its own python and its packages. I've tried Arch Linux and Debian 12, system fully up to date. Any help really appreciated.

I've installed libcrypto.so.1, libffi.so.7 and wxPython. Everything seems to work except the GUI windows.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to ask Simics support. It sounds like their job to solve such problems their customers are facing, and they may have already figured this out for another customer.

Comment: pts, this is a good way to reach Simics support team for the public version of Simics.

Answer (score 0):

Patryk, have you installed the software mentioned in the installation guide? In particular "GTK 2.24 or newer"
Best regards
Simon
#IAmIntel

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be comment.

Comment: If a question together with a specification helped Patryk, is that a bad thing?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. You most likely miss the GTK2 library.

If you run `./simics-gui` you should get a more explicit error message (`Import failed: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`). If such is case, you just need to install libgtk2.

On Fedora, `sudo dnf install gtk2`. On Debian, probably `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0` (untested).

You do *not* need to install wxPython as it is bundled with Simics.